# Android scientific calculator

Tags: android

I am new so please be patient with me.
What I want is to build an advanced calculator for android. I need to convert a string variable (ex. "3+5^8") into a math equation.. I am looking for something  like the eval() function for excel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is a math parser. You can try to port an existing one to Android or create your own using [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/).

Comment: can you suggest an excisting?